# Nginx reverse proxy for Proxmox PVE Datacenter console

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxmox

I am running Proxmox VE Datacenter console on the web behind an SSL protect NGINX proxy. Everything works great as long as I keep the Proxmox VE Datacenter console of the root (i.e.: https://my-site.org/  gets me the Datacenter console).

What I want to do, have tried and failed, is to have the datacenter console behind another URL, for example https://my-site.org/proxmox.

Any ideas?

Comment: please edit the post and put your nginx config there.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by finding a work-around; I used wildcards and redirected https://promox.my-site.org to the proxmox VE Datacenter Console freeing up the my-site.org/ path for the home page which was the goal.